# Поиск по массиву строк в C++ с использованием регулярных выражений

Tags: java, c++, массивы, регулярные-выражения, android-ndk

Добрый день, поскольку учился программировать с C# и Java, то языки ниже этих для меня лес. Понадобилось реализовать код под С++ (Android NDK), аналогичный такому на Java:

```
String z = "";
Pattern x = Pattern.compile("reg");
for(String s : Array) {
  if(x.mather(s).matches())
     z=s;
}
```

Еще интересует,большой ли будет выигрыш в скорости, если для поиска по большому массиву использовать нативный код?

Comment: Некоторые версии gcc не поддерживают регулярки полностью. И выиграш может быть сомнительный.
Но в целом, нужно смотреть задачу. Подозреваю, что простой код отсечения заведомо неверных значений даст больше прирост. Уже профайлили?

Comment: @KoVadim , замерял код в общем (крупные массивы перебираются помногу раз разными регулярками). По максимуму оптимизировал код и регулярки, но 2 секунды на выполнение задачи в целом - все равно много (около 1500мс уходит именно на перебор). Вот и думаю в сторону NDK

Comment: Грамотно написанный ndk-код конечно даст прирост. С java я не экспериментировал, но писал простой код, который использовал регулярки и парсил текст на perl, c++Qt и go. Так вот одни и теже регулярки в перле сильно быстрее (до двух раз).

Поэтому, напишите для начала код отбрасывания заведомо неверных вариантов (например, для коротких строк не применять, или точно знаем, что строка должна  начинаться на цифру и тому подобное)

Comment: @KoVadim, увы, логика такая, что строка может быть любого размера и особых признаков для отсеивания нет, только соответствие шаблону. В паттерны максимум инфы добавил, сделал обращение к методам с перебором минимальным, упорядочил массивы по часто встречаемым, но все равно многовато по времени выходит. Осталось либо урезать массивы(что нежелательно), либо юзать ндк

Comment: Может регулярку покажете? может там рекурсивная регулярка с откатами и работать будет конечно долго.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) смотрите в сторону PIRE- это библиотека от яндекса, которая частично реализует функционал pcre и главное ее назначение- очень быстрый проход массива строк одним или несколькими регулярными выражениями- как раз Ваш случай. Там весь движок регулярных выражений оптимизирован именно под эту цель.

2) естественно прирост будет, если массив будет целиком передан в нативный код. В Java безумно медленные встроенные регулярные выражения. Даже после прогрева, JIT обоих уровней.

3) используйте более производительные библиотеки для Java, типа jRegex.

Comment: Пункты отсортированы в размере прироста производительности.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то приведенный вами код находит последний элемент массива, соответствующий регулярному выражению. В C++11 это делается так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <regex>
int main(){
    std::vector<std::string> strings = {"baaa", "aaab", "baab", "abab"};

    std::regex regex(".aa.");
    auto match = [&](const std::string &str){return std::regex_match(str, regex);};
    auto lastMatch = std::find_if(strings.rbegin(), strings.rend(), match);

    if(lastMatch == strings.rbegin()){
        std::cout << "not found";
    }
    else{
        std::cout << *lastMatch;
    }
}
```

В коде для краткости я использовал лямбду. Сам бы я написал так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <regex>

struct Match{
    std::regex regex;
    explicit Match(const std::string &regex):
        regex(regex)
    {}
    inline bool operator()(const std::string &string) const{
        return std::regex_match(string, regex);
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<std::string> strings = {"baaa", "aaab", "baab", "abab"};
    auto lastMatch = std::find_if(strings.rbegin(), strings.rend(), Match(".aa."));

    if(lastMatch == strings.rbegin()){
        std::cout << "not found";
    }
    else{
        std::cout << *lastMatch;
    }
}
```